# Add TailwindCSS to Phoenix with Brunch

Tags: sass, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch, tailwind-css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add npm packages which are not specifically built to be used with brunch to my elixir/phoenix project.

One thing I don't want to do is manually copy files from `node_modules/` to `vendor/`.

If anyone knows how to properly configure Brunch to use Tailwind in a Phoenix app, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include postcss-brunch and tailwindcss packages

```bash
$ npm install postcss-brunch tailwindcss --save-dev
```

Create Tailwind config file (in assets directory)

```bash
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tailwindcss init
```

Add Tailwind as postcss plugin (assets/brunch-config.js)

```js
// Configure your plugins
plugins: {
    babel: {
        // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
        ignore: [/vendor/]
    },
    postcss: {
        processors: [
            require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.js')
        ]
    }
},
```

Use Tailwind in css (assets/css/app.css)

```css
@tailwind preflight;
@tailwind utilities;
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: mix phx.new defaults to using brunch. This is the simplest set of instructions.

Answer (score 5):

For Phoenix 1.4 I've made a blog post about how you can setup it. https://equimper.com/blog/how-to-setup-tailwindcss-in-phoenix-1.4 This is using webpack and postcss

Create project `mix phx.new myproject`

Go in your assets `cd assets`

Add tailwind dependencies `yarn add -D tailwindcss`

Init tailwind theme `./node_modules/.bin/tailwind init`

Add postcss dep `yarn add -D postcss-loader`

Create a file in `/assets` call `postcss-config.js` and add this code

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.js'), require('autoprefixer')],
}
```

Inside your webpack config change

```js
use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
```

for

```js
use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
```

Finally add those tailwind stuff in your app.css file

```css
@tailwind preflight;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21553850)

Comment: Thank you @Dherik I just upload the essential part :) Thank you for the review